# Cannot get WordPress plugin to paginate correctly

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to build a plug-in for WordPress. The goal is to use a shortcode where I want the `!--nextpage-->` tag to go (pagination), and then for regular visitors (who are not logged in) have pagination in my posts, but for all logged in visitors, have the post keep going without ever seeing pagination (to encourage people to become members).

The problem is, I can get it to not show anything for logged in members, but it loads the page without adding the pagination for non-logged in visitors with this code. So they still see the entire contents just with the links in the middle of it and no pagination.

What do I need to tweak to make it load properly?

```
function pagination_show( $atts = null ) {

    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'nextpage_text' => 'CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE',
        'previous_text' => 'CONTINUED FROM PREVIOUS PAGE',
    ), $atts ) );
    $pagination = '';

    if(!is_user_logged_in()){
        $pagination = '<div class="plugin-pagination" style="overflow:auto;">';

        $next_post = get_next_post();
        if (!empty( $next_post )): 
            $pagination .= '<strong style="float:left;" class="nextpage"><em><a href="'.get_permalink( $next_post->ID ).'">'. esc_attr($nextpage_text) .'</a></strong></em><!--nextpage-->';
        endif;

        $prev_post = get_previous_post();
        if (!empty( $prev_post )): 
            $pagination .= '<strong style="float:right;" class="previouspage"><em><a href="'.get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ).'">'. esc_attr($previous_text) .'</a></strong></em><!--previouspage-->';
        endif;

        $pagination .= '</div>';
    }
    return  $pagination ;
}

add_shortcode('pagination', 'pagination_show');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [wp_link_pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) for the pagination.

The for logged in users, use the_content filter to show the content without the pagination.

e.g., in your post.php (or whatever template) file

```
if( is_user_logged_in() ) :
  echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
else :
  the_content();
  wp_link_pages( $my_args );
endif;
```

Comment: Thank you. I cannot get it to work still. I hired a freelancer to do this. I appreciate your reply very much.